# do ...while и пример из книги

Tags: java

друзья! Не могу понять почему выводит с 1 до 10, а не до 11, если сначала выполняется, а потом проверяется условие

```
class DoWhileDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int count = 1;
        do {
            System.out.println("Count is: " + count);
            count++;
        } while (count < 11);
    }
}
```

Comment: Возьмите листок бумаги и карандаш, и пройдите код по шагам, записывая значения переменных.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Заходим на последний круг:

1. Печатаем "Count is: 10".
2. Прибавляем 1 к 10, получаем 11.
3. Сравниваем 11 с 11. 11 не меньше 11. Условие не выполняется --> Покидаем цикл.

Если написать `count <= 11`, то будет печататься и 11.

Answer (score 1):

В момент когда count = 10 выполняется инкремент и переменная count становится равна 11, в условии while (count < 11) мы прекращаем работу цикла если count < 11.

Comment: _в условии while (count < 11) мы прекращаем работу цикла если count < 11_- нет, если count < 11, то цикл как раз продолжается.

Comment: Да, верно. Условие продолжается до тех про пока count < 11, как только count становится 11 мы прекращаем выполнение цикла.